# Get Data From SQL and put it in a list / Acces another Class without Static?

Tags: c#, sql, list

I'm using SQLite in Unity to try to display some information from a database.

But i've got some issue, I don't know what's missing to get it work.

```
public class City // List
{
    public  int vID { get; set; }
    public  string vName{ get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class training : MonoBehaviour {

public List<City> LoadCity()
{
    var listOfCity = new List<City>();

    string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/DataBase/db_01.s3db";
    IDbConnection dbconn;
    dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
    dbconn.Open(); 
    IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();

    string sqlQuery = "SELECT r_id,r_name "+" FROM region ";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        var city = new City();
        city.vID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["r_id"]);
        city.vName = reader["r_name"].ToString();

        listOfCity.Add(city);
    }

    reader.Close();
    reader = null;
    dbcmd.Dispose();
    dbcmd = null;
    dbconn.Close();
    dbconn = null;

    return listOfCity;

}

void OnGUI() 
{ 
    for (int ai = 0; ai < LoadCity().Count; ai++)
    {
        GUI.Button(new Rect (25, 50+(ai+1)*35, 210, 30),(City.vName[ai]));
        Debug.Log(City.vName[ai]);

    }    
}
}
```

Why in void GUI I can't call City.vName?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because City.vName is not a static member that is the reason you are unable to access that, try making vName static in the class using the following code:

```
    public class City // List
    {
        public  int vID { get; set; }
        public  static string vName{ get; set; }
    }
```

In fact you may do the job without calling City.vName. In your case, you can just catch the list from LoadCity() function and then iteratively access the vName from that list using `listOfCity.vName[ai]`

Comment: Thanks this one work too. `var listOfCity = LoadCity();` then `listOfCity[ai].vName`

Comment: I think this answer is better than the other one. That said Thanks everyone for your help ;)

Comment: Still both answers are valid and working - maybe you should mark them both ?

Comment: I'll but I can't, Maybe I'm too new on the board. (but you get my upvote) :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void OnGUI()
{

    int ai = 0;
    foreach(var city in LoadCity())
    {
        GUI.Button(new Rect (25, 50+(ai+1)*35, 210, 30),(city.vName));
        Debug.Log(city.vName);
        ai++;
    }
}
```

Let me know if any problems.

Comment: I just add a var `foreach(var city in Loadcity())`

Answer (score 0):

In your OnGui() func you load all your data to list and just go through it. Then when you refer to City you don't indicate to a specific object, just to a class name. Therefore you need to indicate to a specific object to get his value.
Try this:

```
var listOfCity =LoadCity();
foreach (var city in listOfCity)
{
    GUI.Button(new Rect (25, 50+(ai+1)*35, 210, 30),(city.vName));
    Debug.Log(city.vName);

}
```

}

Comment: vName is string and not Array